# What does the scene where Shino holds a baby above her head refer to?

Tags: seitokai-yakuindomo

There's this scene in *Seitokai Yakuindomo* (8:55 in this [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/1HljXeQTYm0?t=8m55s)) where Shino holds a baby above her head with lightning in the background and exclaims 'This is my son!'.

[image: Shino holding a baby]

I've seen this reference elsewhere but I'm not sure which show its referencing.

What does this scene refer to?

Comment: [Lion King?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igGEm.jpg)

Comment: I thought it might be but I saw a similar reference in another show that I forget the name of, which made it seem like this is a parody of a scene from an older anime.

Answer (score -1):

its the lion king or for a real stretching it could be referring to the scene in ROOTS where Toby is proclaiming his son to his dead wife.